# Preventing resized images from enlarge

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Im trying to resize photos with different resolution, so i have to know how to limit minimal properties of image.
I want to print my photos 6x8, so i need fixed height(1800), proportional width:

```
mogrify -resize x1800 *.JPG
```

But how to prevent resizing if image smaller than x1800? They will enlarge up to 1800 height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out the software instructions can usually give you the answer: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Try

```
mogrify -resize x1800> *.JPG
```

Comment: oh, such simple. It's better solution than my one. But for windows it's should be - "x1800>"

Comment: That command will cause an error on Linux and Macs btw because `>` is interpreted by the shell. So, on such systems you would need to escape it by preceding it with a backslash, i.e. `x1800\>` A better solution is to use `"x1800>"` which will work on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Found fx expressions, so i can

```
magick 1.jpg -resize "x%[fx:(h>1800)?1800:h]" 2.JPG
```